# findViewByID Method does not Accept listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have tried to write a short Android Application, and am currently failing when implementing a ListView into my Activity (which extends ListActivity). All solutions i have found do not work.

The **findViewByID** method does not accept **R.id.listview** as an argument, the error message being:

> "error: cannot find symbol variable listview"

Yet this is the way every tutorial and example do this simple step. I have altered the ID in the xml File in every way i could imagine, now have it back to **" android:id="@android:id/list" "**.

> Now here is the Activity:

```
package com.example.roman.romansrecipes;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView l;
String[] recipes ={"R1", "R2", "R2"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    l = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, recipes);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
    l.setOnItemClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView temp = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

> and here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.roman.romansrecipes.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your ListView has an ID of "list" and not "listview", which you should declare like this in your XML anyway: android:id="@+id/list". Then you fetch it using findViewById(R.id.list).

Answer (score 3):

Because `android.R.id.xxx` only works for predefined values in the Android framework, and listView isn't one of those. For IDs you create, use `R.id.xxx` without the android.

Answer (score 1):

First you cannot name id's like the way you are doing and secondly you should  use the same id name in your activity.

Change your `id` like:

```
android:id="@+id/myListView"
```

and then:

```
l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to initialize `ListView` in `ListViewActivity`. `ListViewActivity` will automatically initialize `ListView` as you have used id `android:id/list`. To set adapter to `Listview` you just have to call `setListAdapter(adapter);`. And if you want to access `ListView` just get the `ListView` by calling `getListView()` method.

Update your `onCreate` method

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //l = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.listview);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, recipes);
   //l.setAdapter(adapter);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
   //l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
   getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
```

Check about [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)